# How to implement a Master Detail Form as part of a MultiPageEditor in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, master-detail

I have created a sample multi page editor via the Eclipse wizard. Now, I want to extend this editor with a Master Detail Form, so basically, there should be two pages, one standard text editor and the beforesaid Master Detail Form.

**Please note:** I am using this a [demo code](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html) for my `MasterDetailsPage.java`.

Here is my code so far:

MultiPageEditor:

```
package multipageeditortest.editors;


import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResourceChangeEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResourceChangeListener;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ErrorDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.FontData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FontDialog;
import org.eclipse.ui.*;
import org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE;

/**
 * An example showing how to create a multi-page editor.
 * This example has 3 pages:
 * <ul>
 * <li>page 0 contains a nested text editor.
 * <li>page 1 allows you to change the font used in page 2
 * <li>page 2 shows the words in page 0 in sorted order
 * </ul>
 */
public class MultiPageEditor extends MultiPageEditorPart implements IResourceChangeListener{

    /** The text editor used in page 0. */
    private TextEditor editor;

    /** The font chosen in page 1. */
    private Font font;

    /** The text widget used in page 2. */
    private StyledText text;
    /**
     * Creates a multi-page editor example.
     */
    public MultiPageEditor() {
        super();
        ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(this);
    }
    /**
     * Creates page 0 of the multi-page editor,
     * which contains a text editor.
     */
    void createPage0() {
        try {
            editor = new TextEditor();
            int index = addPage(editor, getEditorInput());
            setPageText(index, editor.getTitle());
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            ErrorDialog.openError(
                getSite().getShell(),
                "Error creating nested text editor",
                null,
                e.getStatus());
        }
    }
    /**
     * Creates page 1 of the multi-page editor,
     * which allows you to change the font used in page 2.
     */
    void createPage1() {

        Composite composite = new Composite(getContainer(), SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        composite.setLayout(layout);
        layout.numColumns = 2;

        Button fontButton = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
        GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.BEGINNING);
        gd.horizontalSpan = 2;
        fontButton.setLayoutData(gd);
        fontButton.setText("Change Font...");

        fontButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                setFont();
            }
        });

        int index = addPage(composite);
        setPageText(index, "Properties");
    }
    /**
     * Creates page 2 of the multi-page editor,
     * which shows the sorted text.
     */
    void createPage2() {
        Composite composite = new Composite(getContainer(), SWT.NONE);
        FillLayout layout = new FillLayout();
        composite.setLayout(layout);
        text = new StyledText(composite, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        text.setEditable(false);

        int index = addPage(composite);
        setPageText(index, "Preview");
    }

    void createMasterDetailPage() {
        int index = addPage(new MasterDetailsPage(this)); // ERROR
        setPageText(index, "Master Detail Page");
    }

    /**
     * Creates the pages of the multi-page editor.
     */
    protected void createPages() {
        createPage0();
        createPage1();
        createPage2();
        createMasterDetailPage();
    }
    /**
     * The <code>MultiPageEditorPart</code> implementation of this 
     * <code>IWorkbenchPart</code> method disposes all nested editors.
     * Subclasses may extend.
     */
    public void dispose() {
        ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().removeResourceChangeListener(this);
        super.dispose();
    }
    /**
     * Saves the multi-page editor's document.
     */
    public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        getEditor(0).doSave(monitor);
    }
    /**
     * Saves the multi-page editor's document as another file.
     * Also updates the text for page 0's tab, and updates this multi-page editor's input
     * to correspond to the nested editor's.
     */
    public void doSaveAs() {
        IEditorPart editor = getEditor(0);
        editor.doSaveAs();
        setPageText(0, editor.getTitle());
        setInput(editor.getEditorInput());
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * Method declared on IEditorPart
     */
    public void gotoMarker(IMarker marker) {
        setActivePage(0);
        IDE.gotoMarker(getEditor(0), marker);
    }
    /**
     * The <code>MultiPageEditorExample</code> implementation of this method
     * checks that the input is an instance of <code>IFileEditorInput</code>.
     */
    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput editorInput)
        throws PartInitException {
        if (!(editorInput instanceof IFileEditorInput))
            throw new PartInitException("Invalid Input: Must be IFileEditorInput");
        super.init(site, editorInput);
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * Method declared on IEditorPart.
     */
    public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() {
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Calculates the contents of page 2 when the it is activated.
     */
    protected void pageChange(int newPageIndex) {
        super.pageChange(newPageIndex);
        if (newPageIndex == 2) {
            sortWords();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Closes all project files on project close.
     */
    public void resourceChanged(final IResourceChangeEvent event){
        if(event.getType() == IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_CLOSE){
            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    IWorkbenchPage[] pages = getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getPages();
                    for (int i = 0; i<pages.length; i++){
                        if(((FileEditorInput)editor.getEditorInput()).getFile().getProject().equals(event.getResource())){
                            IEditorPart editorPart = pages[i].findEditor(editor.getEditorInput());
                            pages[i].closeEditor(editorPart,true);
                        }
                    }
                }            
            });
        }
    }
    /**
     * Sets the font related data to be applied to the text in page 2.
     */
    void setFont() {
        FontDialog fontDialog = new FontDialog(getSite().getShell());
        fontDialog.setFontList(text.getFont().getFontData());
        FontData fontData = fontDialog.open();
        if (fontData != null) {
            if (font != null)
                font.dispose();
            font = new Font(text.getDisplay(), fontData);
            text.setFont(font);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Sorts the words in page 0, and shows them in page 2.
     */
    void sortWords() {

        String editorText =
            editor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(editor.getEditorInput()).get();

        StringTokenizer tokenizer =
            new StringTokenizer(editorText, " \t\n\r\f!@#\u0024%^&*()-_=+`~[]{};:'\",.<>/?|\\");
        ArrayList editorWords = new ArrayList();
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            editorWords.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
        }

        Collections.sort(editorWords, Collator.getInstance());
        StringWriter displayText = new StringWriter();
        for (int i = 0; i < editorWords.size(); i++) {
            displayText.write(((String) editorWords.get(i)));
            displayText.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        text.setText(displayText.toString());
    }
}
```

MasterDetailsPage:

```
public class MasterDetailsPage extends FormPage {
    private ScrolledPropertiesBlock block;
    public MasterDetailsPage(FormEditor editor) {
        super(editor, "fourth", "test"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        block = new ScrolledPropertiesBlock(this);
    }
    protected void createFormContent(final IManagedForm managedForm) {
        final ScrolledForm form = managedForm.getForm();
        //FormToolkit toolkit = managedForm.getToolkit();
        form.setText("Test"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        block.createContent(managedForm);
    }
}
```

The problem is in this method:

```
void createMasterDetailPage() {
    int index = addPage(new MasterDetailsPage(this)); // ERROR
    setPageText(index, "Master Detail Page");
}
```

How can I add the `MasterDetailsPage` to my MultiPageEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally use `FormEditor` rather than `MultiPageEditorPart` when using `FormPage` (`FormEditor` extends `MultiPageEditorPart`).

`FormEditor` has an `addPage` that accepts a `FormPage`.